# Dockerize application running on RedHat - how to approach?

Tags: docker, redhat

I am trying to dockerize the application which runs on RHEL7. Application is built based on 3 separate components that require each other. Components run on 3 separate virtual servers. I am now trying to dockerize each component to separate container - meaning:

current setup:

- component 1 - RHEL VM 1
- component 2 - RHEL VM 2
- component 3 - RHEL VM 3

desired setup:

- component 1 - container 1
- component 2 - container 2
- component 3 - container 3

I am not sure what base image to use for each component (rpm packages). Should it be red hat base image, even when os layer is indeed rhel7?

Comment: I think this question is currently too broad for Stack Overflow. You don't have a specific problem you're trying to solve. If you have a configuration that has been validated on RHEL, then using RHEL-based containers seems like a reasonable solution. Honestly, though, the base distribution used in your container is much less important than the application version you're using, and as long as there aren't support implications in your decision just pick whatever is easiest to work with. If they exist, prefer official Docker images rather than building your own.

Comment: Application version is not a problem for me at all. I just couldn't find the answer on what if the app is red hat based, should I use redhad base image?

Comment: I've done my best to address that question in my previous comment. I think the answer is largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: The idea behind containerisation is to use as small a base image as possible with all the necessary run times to run the application. I would also think that you would experience licensing issues when running Red Hat on containers. For this reason, if you want to keep the container distro as close as possible as the container host, maybe use Centos or Fedora.